# how to use a column of df in a pivot table more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like this but I need to convert it to a pivot table like the below one. to sum up, I need to use item columns more than one in a pivot table. I have tried to use aggfunc but how can I define it for items themselves. Could anyone please give a trick about that?

| index | item | interval | transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | x2 | 2 |
| 2 | b | x1 | 2 |

Transformed Table

| x1 |  | x2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item | count | item | count |
| a | 1 | a | 2 |
| b | 2 | b | 0 |

Comment: a question is: why do you need that specific shape where the `item` column is duplicated?

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to obtain the information you want in a natural way ("natural": easy to express in pandas, e.g. using `pivot_table()` or `groupby()`). In order to make the full product of `interval x item` (with `0` for missing pairs), you may use:

```
df.pivot_table(index='interval', columns='item', values='transaction',
               aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

# out:
item      a  b
interval      
x1        1  2
x2        2  0
```

The trick however is how to reshape this into the specific format you asked for. This will involve **duplicating** the `'item'` column or level (something that pandas, understandably, is not particularly fond of). The following is the full operation in one chained sequence:

```
df2 = (df
     .pivot_table(index='interval', columns='item', values='transaction',
                  aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
     .stack().to_frame('count')
     .reset_index('item').set_index('item', append=True, drop=False)
     .unstack('interval').swaplevel(axis=1)
     .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
     .reset_index(drop=True)
    )

# df2:
interval   x1         x2      
         item count item count
0           a     1    a     2
1           b     2    b     0
```

You can comment out from the end to see the various stages. Let's break this down line by line after the `pivot_table`:

Move item to level-1 multiindex and rename the sum as 'count'

```
...     .stack().to_frame('count')
               count
interval item       
x1       a         1
         b         2
x2       a         2
         b         0
```

Duplicate the `item` column (in order to unstack later):

```
...     .reset_index('item').set_index('item', append=True, drop=False)
              item  count
interval item            
x1       a       a      1
         b       b      2
x2       a       a      2
         b       b      0
```

Unstack the `interval`, and swap the levels of the new multiindex columns (note: that's why we needed to duplicate `item`: otherwise `unstack()` would operate on a regular index (not MultiIndex), and as such would convert to a Series):

```
...     .unstack('interval').swaplevel(axis=1)
interval   x1   x2    x1    x2
         item item count count
item                          
a           a    a     1     2
b           b    b     2     0
```

Finally, sort the columns MultiIndex and drop the (now useless) index:

```
...     .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
...     .reset_index(drop=True)
interval   x1         x2      
         item count item count
0           a     1    a     2
1           b     2    b     0
```